# AADSTS90081: An error occurred when we tried to process a WS-Federation message. The message was invalid

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, ws-federation

Testing WS-Federation - Passive Requestor Profile implementation in my custom STS against a federated domain in AAD using web-browser (https://outlook.office365.com/owa).

I am able to HTTP-POST the response (RSTR) to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf after successful authentication at custom STS/ IdP, but somehow following error is showing in the screen.

> Sign In
>
> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad
>   request.
>
> Additional technical information:
>
> Correlation ID: 245b8d44-c4a5-46fc-a8c3-427c27791863
>
> Timestamp: 2017-06-14 06:19:26Z
>
> **AADSTS90081: An error occurred when we tried to process a WS-Federation message. The message was invalid.**

Please refer posted RSTR below.

Also I couldn't see any audit logs corresponding to this message invalid error in https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Audit.

Any idea what I am missing here? or Is there a way to see federated domain's error logs in Azure AD admin portal?

Please advice.

```
wsresult = <t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
   <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
   <t:RequestedSecurityToken>
      <saml:Assertion AssertionID="id-HwkRp-evkRNQDektd-zMdRKZ74LuDuuWhec-J9Lt" IssueInstant="2017-06-14T03:07:07Z" Issuer="urn:fed:mySts" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1">
         <dsig:Signature>
            <dsig:SignedInfo>
               <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
               <dsig:Reference URI="#id-HwkRp-evkRNQDektd-zMdRKZ74LuDuuWhec-J9Lt">
                  <dsig:Transforms>
                     <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                     <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </dsig:Transforms>
                  <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                  <dsig:DigestValue>D5DvtVT9y/tvKKK1+CmmMRL95Ogg+9lZUkGB9crTC/w=</dsig:DigestValue>
               </dsig:Reference>
            </dsig:SignedInfo>
            <dsig:SignatureValue>YEUp7GuC5qwEYUw4iKxrkezBKd8TetLiKkx63JTt6oizAzSQsLahDTlo3Pl/Na0tJEApLVMICsriZotNRQLrM9MuqI2cmYLqHGaK1LWs3euRwkT1hq6tHKuSkl7yGew4PYB/ZOVSAqHxDx1G2A3AkbYXu/IgHoeBnghdwszbYbs=</dsig:SignatureValue>
            <dsig:KeyInfo>
               <dsig:X509Data>
                  <dsig:X509Certificate>MIICUDCCAbmgAwIBAgIELfGcX...</dsig:X509Certificate>
               </dsig:X509Data>
            </dsig:KeyInfo>
         </dsig:Signature>
         <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-06-14T03:06:37Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-06-14T03:12:37Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
               <saml:Audience>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
         </saml:Conditions>
         <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2017-06-14T03:07:07Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password">
            <saml:Subject>
               <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">4JRuZcPlfk+syK/x5WMgbA=</saml:NameIdentifier>
               <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                  <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
               </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
         </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
         <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Subject>
               <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">4JRuZcPlfk+syK/x5WMgbA=</saml:NameIdentifier>
               <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                  <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
               </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="UPN" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
               <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">xyz@abc.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="ImmutableID" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveID/Federation/2008/05">
               <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">4JRuZcPlfk+syK/x5WMgbA=</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="objectGUID" AttributeNamespace="http://tempuri.com">
               <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">4JRuZcPlfk+syK/x5WMgbA=</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
         </saml:AttributeStatement>
      </saml:Assertion>
   </t:RequestedSecurityToken>
   <wp:AppliesTo>
      <wsa:EndpointReference>
         <wsa:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:EndpointReference>
   </wp:AppliesTo>
   <t:Lifetime>
      <Created>2017-06-14T03:06:37Z</Created>
      <Expires>2017-06-14T03:12:37Z</Expires>
   </t:Lifetime>
</t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```